# How to turn a Django Rest Framework API View into an async one?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I am trying to build a REST API that will manage some machine learning classification tasks. I have written an API view, which when hit, will trigger the start of a classification task (such as: training an SVM classifier with the data the user provided previously). However, this is a long running task, so I would ideally not have the user wait once they have made a request to this view. Instead, I would like to start this task in the background and give them a response immediately. They can later view the results of the classification in a separate view (haven't implemented that yet.)

I am using `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mlxplorebackend.asgi.application'` in `settings.py`.

Here's my API view in `views.py`

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from django import setup as SetupDjango

# ... other imports

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def DummyClassification():
  result = sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))
  print(result)
  return result

# ... other API views

class TaskExecuteView(APIView):
  """
  Once an API call is made to this view, the classification algorithm will start being processed.
  Depends on:
  1. Parser for the classification algorithm type and parameters
  2. Classification algorithm implementation
  """

  def get(self, request, taskId, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      task = TaskModel.objects.get(taskId = taskId)
    except TaskModel.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404
    else:
      # this is basically the classification task for now
      # need to turn this to an async view      
      with ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer = SetupDjango) as pool:
        loop.run_in_executor(pool, DummyClassification)

      return Response({ "message": "The task with id: {} has been started".format(task.taskId) }, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem I am facing is the following:

1. When I do not use `with ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer = SetupDjango) as pool:` i.e. without the initializer, I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` (full traceback at: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ctjmFNYMXW/)
2. When I do use the initializer, the view no longer remains async, it gets blocked. The response returns after the task is completed, which is about 5 seconds on my machine. I do realize I am not really making use of `asyncio.sleep()` inside my `DummyClassification()` function, but I can't figure out the way to do so.

I am guessing this is not the way to do it, therefore any suggestions would be appreciated. I would like to avoid celery if I can, since that seems a tad bit too complicated for me.

Edit:
If I get rid of `ProcessPoolExecutor()` and simply do `loop.run_in_executor(None, DummyClassification)`, it works as expected, but then only one worker thread is working on the task, which doesn't seem remotely ideal for a classification task.

Comment: The problem is that the `with` statement shuts down the process pool at the end of the block, which is **not** what you want because the cleanup entails waiting for scheduled tasks to finish. You probably want to initialize the pool only once in a global variable, and not use `with` at all.

Comment: Also, `run_in_executor` returns an object that you're supposed to `await` in an async event loop. If you never do that, you might as well use the pool directly with `pool.submit()`. In either case, you need to store the object returned by either `run_in_executor` or `submit`, and use it to retrieve the result later, or at least to determine that the task is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a ride. I at first went through the pain of setting up `celery` only to find out that the original problem of the classification task using one CPU core remains. Then I switched to `django-rq` with `redis` and it is currently working as expected.

```
from .tasks import Pipeline

class TaskExecuteView(APIView):
  """
  Once an API call is made to this view, the classification algorithm will start being processed.
  Depends on:
  1. Parser for the classification algorithm type
  2. Classification algorithm implementation
  """

  def get(self, request, taskId, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      task = TaskModel.objects.get(taskId = taskId)
    except TaskModel.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404
    else:
      Pipeline.delay(taskId) # this is async now ✔

      # mark this as an in-progress task
      TaskModel.objects.filter(taskId = taskId).update(inProgress = True)

      return Response({ "message": "The task with id: {}, title: {} has been started".format(task.taskId, task.taskTitle) }, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`tasks.py`

```
from django_rq import job

@job('default', timeout=3600)
def Pipeline(taskId):
  # classification task
```